# Getting JSON object from for loop

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm trying to create a simple link re-director.

I have an Express server running like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const path = require('path');
const json = require('awesome-json')

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('henlo!'))

app.get('/:short', (req, res) => {
    var short = req.params.short
    json.read('redirect', (err, contents) => {
        for(var i in contents) {
            if(i == short) res.redirect(contents.git)
        }
    })
})


app.listen(1337, () => console.log('henlo'))
```

My JSON file looks like this

`{"git":"https://github.com/"}`

If the `i` variable matches contents, how would I get the link?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access a dynamic property of an object using the square bracket notation:

```
if(i == short)
  res.redirect(contents[i])
```

You can read more [clicking here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).